# Why is this query taking so much longer when I switched from >= DATE to BETWEEN DATE and DATE?

Tags: mysql, optimization, greatest-n-per-group

This query is taking forever to complete.  When I set the WHERE clause to new_dl >= '2014-01-01', the query took about 6 minutes to go through the approx 3 months of data.  Not sure now why this query that should be selecting from 12 months of data has been running for an hour and twenty minutes and has still not completed.

```
SELECT      customers.kayako_id,
            customers.firstname,
            customers.lastname,
            customers.address1_city,
            customers.address1_stateorprovince,
            customers.address1_postalcode,
            customers.new_product, 
            customers.new_total,
            MAX(last_modified)
FROM        customers
INNER JOIN  (
            SELECT kayako_id, max(new_total) Price
            FROM customers
            GROUP BY kayako_id
            ) NewTable 
            ON customers.kayako_id = NewTable.kayako_id 
            and customers.new_total = NewTable.Price
WHERE       new_dldate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY    customers.kayako_id, 
            customers.firstname, 
            customers.lastname,
            customers.address1_city,
            customers.address1_stateorprovince,
            customers.address1_postalcode,
            customers.new_product, 
            customers.new_total;
```

[image: customers]
[customers http://imageshack.com/a/img543/6840/74do.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img543/6840/74do.png)

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`last_modified` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`kayako_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`firstname` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`lastname` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`new_product` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`new_total` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`new_dldate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`address1_city` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`address1_stateorprovince` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`address1_postalcode` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=432290;

INSERT INTO customers values (1,'2013-01-02', 12345, 'bob', 'smith', 'CLO50', 39.99,'2013-01-02','portland', 'OR',97229);
INSERT INTO customers values (2,'2013-01-04', 12345, 'bob', 'smith', 'CLO50', 29.99,'2013-01-02','portland', 'OR',97229);
INSERT INTO customers values (3,'2013-01-05', 12345, 'bob', 'smith', 'CLO50', 59.99,'2013-01-02','portland', 'OR',97229);
INSERT INTO customers values (4,'2013-01-05', 78654, 'joe', 'guy', 'CLO60', 39.99,'2013-01-02','salem', 'OR',97229);
INSERT INTO customers values (5,'2013-01-05', 45698, 'karen', 'min', 'CLO40', 49.99,'2013-01-02','eugene', 'OR',97229);
INSERT INTO customers values (6,'2014-01-06', 82987, 'sue', 'jones', 'Sub-CLO50', 29.99,'2014-01-02','portland', 'OR',97229);
INSERT INTO customers values (7,'2008-01-02', 39845, 'jack', 'sam', 'CLM50', 49.99,'2008-01-02','corvallis', 'OR',97330);
INSERT INTO customers values (8,'2013-01-05', 65189, 'steve', 'ou', 'CLO50', 59.99,'2013-01-02','portland', 'OR',97229);
INSERT INTO customers values (9,'2013-01-06', 19999, 'matt', 'kim', 'CLO60', 39.99,'2013-01-02','beaverton', 'OR',97005);
INSERT INTO customers values (10,'2013-01-07', 19999, 'matt', 'kim', 'CLO60', 59.99,'2013-01-02','beaverton', 'OR',97005);
INSERT INTO customers values (11,'2013-01-08', 19999, 'matt', 'kim', 'CLO60', 29.99,'2013-01-02','beaverton', 'OR',97005);
```

Comment: please post explain plan and table structure for the customers table (show create table customers).

Comment: 6 minutes? Are you using a mechanical computer?

Comment: Derived queries are not is never good option. Also please share the explain

Comment: Do you have a compound index on (kayako_id,new_total,new_dldate) ?If not, try that.

Comment: This derived query is just fine. i doubt that there's a faster method.

Comment: "Mechanical computer." that made me laugh. No, it is Pentium 4. db is hosted on rackspace a few states away.

Comment: There is an implied redundancy in your design however. That may be causing problems?

Comment: I'm sorry, not sure what the explain is?   I'll add an image of the table structure above.

Comment: EXPLAIN SELECT... customers.new_total \G

Comment: EXPLAIN SELECT added above.

There is redundancy in the customers table, it's not normalized like all of the databases in school have been.  If you are saying my query is redundant, then I'd like to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason of the discrepancy could be that you are selecting different amounts of data:

> WHERE clause to new_dl >= '2014-01-01', the query took about 6 minutes
>
> WHERE       new_dldate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'

The query join time then is not necessarily *linear* (i.e. if you double the number of rows selected, the time approximately doubles). In this case it is *quadratic* - or worse. Which means that if you increase the number of selected rows by a factor of around twelve, the query time grows by a factor of around *one hundred and forty-four*.

In this case, the `customers` table is not, actually, a "customers" table at all since any one customer may appear in there more than once. It's more of a `kayako` table, which ought to be joined with `customers`. In the `kayako` table only the customer id, kayako id, price and last modified are required.

We want to list the maximum price and last modified date of `kayako` inside a given time range. So we need an index on the date as first element, then on `kayako_id` for grouping, and finally we may benefit from having the two other fields in the index as well, to avoid actually hitting the table to get the data we need.

We do this on the `customers` table:

```
CREATE INDEX customers_kayako_ndx ON customers
   (new_dldate, kayako_id, new_total, last_modified);
```

Now we will have several identical "customer" instances from any one kayako and need to select which customer to represent them; we choose the one with greater customer ID... which is probably the same of latest `last_modified`; but see at the bottom too for a different way. The desired selection is then:

```
SELECT
   MAX(id) AS chosen,
   MAX(new_total) AS Price,
   MAX(last_modified) AS modified
FROM customers
WHERE      
   new_dldate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY kayako_id
```

Then we need to enrich this selection with actual customer data; this we do with the JOIN.

```
SELECT
  customers.kayako_id,
  customers.firstname,
  customers.lastname,
  customers.address1_city,
  customers.address1_stateorprovince,
  customers.address1_postalcode,
  customers.new_product, 
  Price,
  last_modified
FROM (
    SELECT
       MAX(id) AS chosen,
       MAX(new_total) AS Price,
       MAX(last_modified) AS modified
    FROM customers
    WHERE      
       new_dldate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'
    GROUP BY kayako_id
  )  AS selection 
  JOIN customers ON (customers.id = selection.chosen)
;
```

To improve performances we could actually split into two different tables altogether, with customers identified by their kayako_id, not their id:

```
CREATE TABLE kayako AS
    SELECT kayako_id, new_total, new_dldate, last_modified
FROM customers;

CREATE TABLE `new_customers` (
`kayako_id` integer not null primary key auto_increment,
`firstname` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`lastname` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`new_product` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`address1_city` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`address1_stateorprovince` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`address1_postalcode` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);
```

The above assumes that `last_modified` is related to kayako. Otherwise, if it refers to a *customer* modification date, it should go into `new_customers` (if you want to keep a customer information history, it would perhaps be best to also add a boolean column `active` to help in the `SELECT`s) and the query should be modified accordingly, by choosing the customer *with latest modification date* and using slightly different indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX customers_kayako_ndx ON customers(new_dldate, kayako_id, new_total, last_modified);
CREATE INDEX customers_join_ndx ON customers (kayako_id, last_modified);

SELECT
  customers.kayako_id,
  customers.firstname,
  customers.lastname,
  customers.address1_city,
  customers.address1_stateorprovince,
  customers.address1_postalcode,
  customers.new_product, 
  Price,
  last_modified
FROM (
    SELECT
       kayako_id,
       MAX(new_total) AS Price,
       MAX(last_modified) AS modified
    FROM customers
    WHERE      
       new_dldate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'
    GROUP BY kayako_id
  )  AS selection 
  JOIN customers ON (
      customers.kayako_id = selection.kayako_id
      AND
      customers.last_modified = selection.last_modified
  )
;
```

Comment: I added a sqlfiddle here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d2960
CREATE and INSERT scripts also added above.

I've never used INDEX, can you show how it would be added to my current query?

Comment: Thanks. Added to answer, together with a rough explanation on how I proceeded and why.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Your SELECT run on the entire year of data took 4.5 seconds vs my query which ran for 15 hours without completing!  I don't have permission to write so I can't create tables or make the indexes but improving the query helped tremendously.